# Android - How to keep the view position not change after calling setVisible(View.GONE)?

Tags: android, layout, view

I have a RootLayout[it can be setted any layout],such as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainRootLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ibtnHidden"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ibtnPlay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ibtnHidden"
        android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ibtnHidden"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_play" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ibtnPreference"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ibtnHidden"
        android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ibtnPlay"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_preferences" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ibtnExit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ibtnHidden"
        android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ibtnPreference"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel" />

</RelativeLayout>

ibtn_Hidden = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.ibtnHidden);
ibtn_Play = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.ibtnPlay);
ibtn_Preference = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.ibtnPreference);
ibtn_Exit = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.ibtnExit);
```

when I call "ibtn_Play.setVisible(View.GONE);ibtn_Preference.setVisible(View.GONE);ibtn_Exit.setVisible(View.GONE)",the ibtn_Hidden's position would changed.

I guess it is because the others have been temporarily removed,the view's size is also changed,and it is towards the middle of change.

How to keep the ibtn_Hidden's position not change after calling setVisible(View.GONE),and the others[ibtn_Play ibtn_Preference ibtn_Exit] should not occupy space?Thank you~

Comment: try this property setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); insted of setVisibility(View.GONE);

Comment: Post your whole layout code.

Comment: Try wrapping your views in LinearLayouts. That way the layout will collapse as the views within it are set to View.GONE but the LinearLayout it's self will remain in position.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a view to not be visible, but still keep it's layout impact, you can use this:

```
imageButton2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to add,I need to remove ImageButton2 and ImageButton3, while maintaining the same position ImageButton1.ImageButton2 and ImageButton3 should not occupy space.thank you

Comment: This does not answer the question, the OP asked specifically about using View.GONE and not View.INVISIBLE.

Answer (score 0):

yes u can use view.visible if your parent position disturb i used view.gone so my parent position disturbs it goes up but in view.visible it remain constant

Comment: Please [edit] and try for [answer].

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).